# Fatal error: Call to undefined function getRecords() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Employees.php on line 101

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have read about this error, but none of the answers seem to apply to my specific issue. The purpose of my code is 3-fold. I am creating a form that populates a database. Then on the same page I want to be able to search the database with a 2nd form and delete records with a 3rd form. I'm working on these issues one at a time, so the code I am posting below is incomplete, but the forms are all there. In case you are wondering why there is a delete form and no code for deleting. :-P. Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly with my function, buildQuery? I believe that is the key to my problem with getRecords. Or not?

```
<html>
<body>

<?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$keyword = $_GET['keyword']; ?>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "employees", "employeepw");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS employees",$con))
  {
  echo "Database created";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
  }

mysql_select_db("employees", $con);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE employeeinfo
(
personID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(personID),
FirstName varchar(15),
LastName varchar(15),
Phone varchar(15),
Email varchar(15),
Department varchar(15),
Position varchar(15),
)";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO employeeinfo (FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, Department, Position)
VALUES ('firstname', 'lastname', 'phone', 'email', 'department', 'position')");

mysql_query($sql,$con);

        function buildQuery() {

        $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];

        $sql = "SELECT * from employeeinfo WHERE
                (
                firstname LIKE '%$keyword%'
                OR
                lastname LIKE '%$keyword%'
                OR
                phone LIKE '%$keyword%'
                OR
                email LIKE '%$keyword%'
                OR
                department LIKE '%$keyword%'
                OR
                position LIKE '%$keyword%'
                )";

        return $sql;

        mysql_close($con);

        } ?>

        <form action="Employees.php" method=get>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Submit Employee Info</legend>
        Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
        Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" />
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
        Department: <input type="text" name="department" />
        Position: <input type="text" name="position" />
        <input type=submit name=submit value=Submit />
        </fieldset>
        </form>

        <form action="Employees.php" method=get>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Search Employee Info</legend>
        <label for="keyword">Enter Keyword</label>
        <input id="keyword" name="keyword" value="<?php echo "$keyword"; ?>" />
        <input type=submit name=submit value=Search />
        </fieldset>
        </form>

        <form action="Employees.php" method=get>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Delete Employee Info</legend>
        <label for="keyword">Enter Keyword</label>
        <input id="keyword" name="keyword" value="<?php echo "$keyword"; ?>" />
        <input type=submit name=submit value=Delete />
        </fieldset>
        </form>

        <?

                $query = buildQuery();

                $records = getRecords($query); //error is in this line

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){ ?>

        <table>

        <tbody>
        <table border='1'>

        <tr>
        <td><?= $row['firstname']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['lastname']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['phone']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['department']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['position']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="Employees.php">Return to Search</a></td>
        </tr>

        <? }

        ?>

</tbody>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you mean `mysql_query` instead of `getRecords`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP cannot locate your getRecords() function.  Have you included the file that this function is defined in?

Edit:

You should really look into securing your posted data, and just general code cleanliness.  It's better to use the functions mysql provides directly, instead of wrapping them in functions that are only usable for one situation.

And: why in the world are you building your entire employeeinfo table each time, or at least checking if it exists? This should be something you do once, and forget about. Then delete that code, because it is confusing.

You should think about how this all should logically work before you dive in. This is basically an employee management system? Looks like you want to be able to: Add new employees, search for employees, edit employees, and delete employees. Here is a basic implementation, its missing the feature to add an employee. I haven't tested this, but I hope it points you in the right direction:

```
    <?php
/* Employees.php */

include('dbfactory.php');
include('header.php');



if(isset($_GET['do']) && (!empty($_GET['do']))){

    switch($_GET['do']){

        case 'search':
            //The form action is appended with a query string, so we can handle multiple cases in process.php
            ?>
                <form action="process.php?do=runsearch" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                <legend>Search Employee Info</legend>
                <label for="keyword">Enter Keyword</label>
                <input id="keyword" name="keyword" value="" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
                </fieldset>
                </form>
            <?php


        break;

        case 'edit':
            //Make sure that the employee id has been set!
            if(isset($_GET['eid']) && (!empty($_GET['eid']))){

                //Get the DB connection
                $db = ConnectionFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

                //Set up the query with a ? placeholder
                $sql = "Select * from employeeinfo WHERE personid = ? LIMIT 1";

                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
                    //Bind the question mark with the Employee ID, as an Integer ONLY
                    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['eid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

                    $stmt->execute();


                /* Get an array of the result */
                $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                /* Make an array of friendly names associated with the mysql fields */
                if(count($result) > 0){
                    //Set up friendly names:
                    $fnames = array('firstname' => 'First Name',
                                'lastname' => 'Last Name',
                                'phone' => 'Phone Number',
                                'email' => 'Email Address',
                                'department' => 'Department',
                                'position' => 'Position');

                    /* Start the form, and make a hidden field with the employee id we want to edit.*/
                    ?>
                    <form action="process.php?do=saveedits" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="personid" value="<?=$result['personid']?>" />
                    <?php

                    /* Unset the person id, because we already used it */
                    unset($result['personid']);

                    //*Fill the fields with values from the database, if a friendly name is found, it will be used as the label*/
                    foreach($result as $key => $value){
                        ?>
                        <label for="<?=$key?>"><?=(isset($fnames["$key"]) ? $fnames["$key"] : $key)?></label>
                        <input id="<?=$key?>" name="<?=$key?>" value="<?=$value?>" />
                        <br>
                        <?php                       
                    }

                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" value="Modify Employee" >
                    </form>
                    <?php



                }
                else{
                    /* Couldnt find that employee in the DB */
                    ?>
                    <h2>Error, Employee Not Found</h2>
                    <?php
                    }
            }

        break;

        case 'new':
            //Make sure that the employee id has been set!

                /* Make an array of friendly names associated with the mysql fields */

                    //Set up friendly names:
                    $fnames = array('firstname' => 'First Name',
                                'lastname' => 'Last Name',
                                'phone' => 'Phone Number',
                                'email' => 'Email Address',
                                'department' => 'Department',
                                'position' => 'Position');

                    /* Start the form, and make a hidden field with the employee id we want to edit.*/
                    ?>
                    <form action="process.php?do=savenew" method="POST">    
                    <?php

                    //*Fill the fields with values from the database, if a friendly name is found, it will be used as the label*/
                    foreach($fnames as $key => $value){
                        ?>
                        <label for="<?=$key?>"><?=$value?></label>
                        <input id="<?=$key?>" name="<?=$key?>" />
                        <br>
                        <?php   

                    }

                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" value="Create New Employee" >
                    </form>
                    <?php


        break;


        case 'delete':

            if(isset($_GET['eid']) && (!empty($_GET['eid']))){
            $db = ConnectionFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

                    /* Make sure this person exists, and get their info */
                    $sql = "Select * from employeeinfo WHERE personid = ?";

                    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
                        /* Same as above */
                        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['eid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

                        $stmt->execute();



                    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    if(count($result) > 0){
                    /* Ask to confirm the delete */
                        ?>
                        <h2>Are you sure you want to delete <?=$result['firstname']?> <?=$result['lastname']?>'s Records?</h2>
                        <a href="process.php?do=confirmdelete&eid=<?=$result['personid']?>">Yes, Confirm Delete!</a>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else{
                        ?>
                        <h2>Error, Employee Not Found</h2>
                        <?php
                        }

            }
            break;



    }
}
else{
//List employees



$db = ConnectionFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();


                    $sql = "SELECT * from employeeinfo";

                    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
                    $res = $stmt->execute();


                    /* Make a table with the results and headings */
                    if($res){
                        ?>
                            <table>
                            <tr>
                            <td>First Name</td>
                            <td>Last Name</td>
                            <td>Email</td>
                            <td>Phone</td>
                            <td>Department</td>
                            <td>Position</td>
                            <td>Actions</td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                    while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                            <td><?=$result['firstname']?></td>
                            <td><?=$result['lastname']?></td>
                            <td><?=$result['email']?></td>
                            <td><?=$result['phone']?></td>
                            <td><?=$result['department']?></td>
                            <td><?=$result['position']?></td>
                            <td><a href="employees.php?do=edit&eid=<?=$result['personid']?>">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <a href="employees.php?do=delete&eid=<?=$result['personid']?>">Del</a>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                        }                   
                        ?>
                            </table>
                        <?php           

                        }


}

include('footer.php');
/* End Employees.php */
?>
```

Process.php:

```
<?php
/* Process.php */


// Bind the parameter


include('dbfactory.php');
include('header.php');


if(isset($_GET['do']) && (!empty($_GET['do']))){

    switch($_GET['do']){

        case 'runsearch':

                if((isset($_POST['keyword'])) && (!empty($_POST['keyword']))){

                /* You have to put the % signs in beforehand with PDO */
                    $keyword = "%".$_POST['keyword']."%";

                    $db = ConnectionFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();


                    $sql = "SELECT * from employeeinfo WHERE 
                    firstname LIKE ? 
                    OR
                    lastname LIKE ? 
                    OR
                    phone LIKE ? 
                    OR
                    email LIKE ? 
                    OR
                    department LIKE ? 
                    OR
                    position LIKE ?";

                    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 

                    /* There are 6 placeholders, so we need to loop 6 times, binding the new placeholder each time */
                    for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){
                        $stmt->bindParam($i, $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    }                   
                    $res = $stmt->execute();


                    /* Make a table with the results and headings */
                    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                        ?>
                            <table>
                            <tr>
                            <td>First Name</td>
                            <td>Last Name</td>
                            <td>Email</td>
                            <td>Phone</td>
                            <td>Department</td>
                            <td>Position</td>
                            <td>Actions</td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php

                    while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                            <td><?=$result['firstname']?></td>
                            <td><?=$result['lastname']?></td>
                            <td><?=$result['email']?></td>
                            <td><?=$result['phone']?></td>
                            <td><?=$result['department']?></td>
                            <td><?=$result['position']?></td>
                            <td><a href="employees.php?do=edit&eid=<?=$result['personid']?>">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <a href="employees.php?do=delete&eid=<?=$result['personid']?>">Del</a>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                        }                   
                        ?>
                            </table>
                        <?php           

                    }
                    else{
                    ?><h2>No Results Found!<?php
                    }

                }
                else{
                ?><h2>No Keyword Set!<?php
                }



        break;

        case 'saveedits':       

            /* Array of the fields we expect to be Posted */
            $required = array('personid' => 'Employee Id',
                                'firstname' => 'First Name',
                                'lastname' => 'Last Name',
                                'phone' => 'Phone Number',
                                'email' => 'Email Address',
                                'department' => 'Department',
                                'position' => 'Position');

            /* Make sure all the fields have been posted */
            $good = true;
            foreach($required as $field => $value){
                if(!isset($_POST[$field]))
                    $good = false;      
            }   

            if($good){

                $db = ConnectionFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
                /* Have to temporarily store the personid in a temp variable, and remove it from the array */
                $pid = $_POST['personid'];
                unset($_POST['personid']);
                $posted = $_POST;

                /* Change this : firstname to : `firstname`=:firstname, etc, etc  Runs over the whole arraay */
                $params = join(", ", array_map(
                function($col) { 
                return "`".preg_replace("/`/u","``",$col)."`=".":".preg_replace("/[`\s]/u","",$col);}, 
                array_keys($posted)));

                /* Put the personid back into the posted array, so we can use it again. */
                $posted['personid'] = $pid;

                $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `employeeinfo` SET {$params} WHERE `personid`=:personid"); 
                /* Use the whole post array to execute looks like: field => value */
                $stmt->execute($posted);

                if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                    ?><h2>Employee Updated!</h2><?php
                }
                else{
                    ?><h2>Error! Could Not Update Employee!</h2><?php
                }
            }
            else{
            print_r($_POST);
            print_r($required);
                ?><h2>Form Error! Required fields not set!</h2><?php
            }


        break;

        case 'savenew':     

            /* Array of the fields we expect to be Posted */
            $required = array('firstname' => 'First Name',
                                'lastname' => 'Last Name',
                                'phone' => 'Phone Number',
                                'email' => 'Email Address',
                                'department' => 'Department',
                                'position' => 'Position');

            /* Make sure all the fields have been posted */
            $good = true;
            foreach($required as $field => $value){
                if(!isset($_POST[$field]))
                    $good = false;      
            }   

            if($good){

                $db = ConnectionFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
                /* Have to temporarily store the personid in a temp variable, and remove it from the array */   
                $posted = $_POST;



                    $columns = join(",", array_map(
                    function($col) { return "`".preg_replace("/`/u","``",$col)."`";}, 
                    array_keys($posted)));

                    $params = join(",", array_map(
                    function($col) { return ":".preg_replace("/[`\s]/u","",$col);},
                    array_keys($posted)));


                    $query = "INSERT INTO `employeeinfo` ({$columns}) VALUES ({$params})";

                    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);   
                    $stmt->execute($posted);

                if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                    ?><h2>Employee Created!</h2><?php
                }
                else{
                    ?><h2>Error! Could Not Create Employee!</h2><?php
                    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
                }
            }
            else{
                ?><h2>Form Error! Required fields not set!</h2><?php
            }


        break;

        /* Pretty Self Explanatory */
        case 'confirmdelete':

                if(isset($_GET['eid']) && (!empty($_GET['eid']))){

                $db = ConnectionFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();


                    $sql = "Delete from `employeeinfo` WHERE personid = ?";


                    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 

                        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['eid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

                        $stmt->execute();

                        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                        ?><h2>Employee Deleted!</h2><?php
                        }
                        else{
                        ?><h2>Error! Could Not Delete Employee!<br></h2><?php
                        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
                        }
                }
                else{
                ?><h2>Error! No Employee By That Id!</h2><?php
                }

        break;


    }
}
else{
//Error nothing to do!
}

/* End process.php: */
?>
```

Dbfactory.php:

```
/* dbfactory.php: */
   <?php
Class ConnectionFactory
{
    private static $factory;
    public static function getFactory()
    {
        if (!self::$factory)
            self::$factory = new ConnectionFactory;
        return self::$factory;
    }

    private $db;

    public function getConnection() {
        if (!isset($db)){

           try{
           //Make sure to fill out these values
            $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=YOURDATABASENAME;host=YOURDATABASEADDRESS', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
            return $db;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {  
            echo 'DB Error: '. $e->getMessage();
            }

        }
    }
}
 ?>
/* End dbfactory.php: */
```

Header.php:

```
/* Header.php: */



<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

td{
border:1px solid;
border-radius:3px;
padding:4px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="employees.php">Manage Employees</a>  -  <a href="employees.php?do=search">Search Employees</a>  -  <a href="employees.php?do=new">Add Employee</a>
<br>
<br>

/* End header.php */
```

Footer.php:

```
   /*footer.php */

</body>
</html>

/* End footer.php */
```

Again this is still basic, and this kind of thing should be implemented into a php Class.
This is using PDO, so if your db details ever change, you just have to alter dbfactory.php, and you are done.

If I could go back and change one thing about starting to learn PHP, it would be to learn PDO instead of the depreceated mysql query functions like you are using.

This is by no means a perfect implementation, like I said, it should all be classed, and logic separated from presentation; but it is a start!

Happy learning!

Comment: Thank you. Looking into that.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, Ben! I will go learn PDO. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question so thoroughly! Lots to comb through.

Comment: Good point about the employeeinfo table. It was not creating the table, but once I figured out why (dumb comma I left at the end), the table was successfully created and I deleted the code.

Comment: Hey, I'll update this in a few minutes, with a version that actually compiles and runs, i wrote this in 25 minutes yesterday, and its got compile errors, It will be updated in a few minutes

Comment: Ok, this works syntactically now. Functionality: Search for employees, Edit Employees, Add New Employees, Delete Employees, and List All Employees(Default)