# Newbie: Building an employee directory with scripts for add/edit/search/delete. Errors

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am building an employee directory that has 3 simple forms. The first adds records, the second searches for records, the third searches then deletes records.I want to display all the records on the same page, and then when a search is done, just display those records that fit the search keyword.

I have built the DB and the Table correctly. The first form adds records to the DB successfully. Before I make the search and delete forms work correctly I am trying to get the records to display. They are not displaying. Sometimes I can get my html table to display, but none of the records appear. However, I know that the records exist because I can see them in MyAdmin.

I am getting this error right now, but my errors are changing by the moment as I try new things: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Employees.php on line 84

I would love some help to do the following:
1. Help me understand why I am getting this error.
2. Help me understand how to display my records (I've done this successfully before, but with a simpler task).

I know this code is unfinished. I am building it piece by piece and trying to get each individual piece to function before I add the next. Thanks!

```
<html>
<body>

<?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$keyword = $_GET['keyword']; ?>

<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "employees", "employeepw");
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db("employees", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO employeeinfo (firstname, lastname, phone, email, department, position)
VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]', '$_POST[lastname]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[department]', '$_POST[position]')");

mysql_query($sql,$con);

        function buildQuery() {

        $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];

        $sql = "SELECT * from employeeinfo WHERE
                (
                firstname LIKE '%$keyword%'
                OR
                lastname LIKE '%$keyword%'
                OR
                phone LIKE '%$keyword%'
                OR
                email LIKE '%$keyword%'
                OR
                department LIKE '%$keyword%'
                OR
                position LIKE '%$keyword%'
                )";

        return $sql;

        } ?>

        <form action="Employees.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Submit Employee Info</legend>
        Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
        Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" />
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
        Department: <input type="text" name="department" />
        Position: <input type="text" name="position" />
        <input type=submit name=submit value=Submit />
        </fieldset>
        </form>

        <form action="Employees.php" method=get>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Search Employee Info</legend>
        <label for="keyword">Enter Keyword</label>
        <input id="keyword" name="keyword" value="<?php echo "$keyword"; ?>" />
        <input type=submit name=submit value=Search />
        </fieldset>
        </form>

        <form action="Employees.php" method=get>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Delete Employee Info</legend>
        <label for="keyword">Enter Keyword</label>
        <input id="keyword" name="keyword" value="<?php echo "$keyword"; ?>" />
        <input type=submit name=submit value=Delete />
        </fieldset>
        </form>

<?
function getRecords()
{
$sql = buildQuery();

$resource = mysql_query($sql);
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resource)) { // The error is for this row
$results[] = $row;
}
return $results;

$records = getRecords(); {

foreach ($records as $record) {

}?>

        <table>
        <tbody>
        <table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <td><?= $row['firstname']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['lastname']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['phone']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['department']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['position']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="Employees.php">Return to Search</a></td>
        </tr>

        <? } ?>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi CherylAnn, you need to add some further debugging to this script. i.e. You are not checking for errors on DB selection or with `mysql_query` (do exactly what you did with `$con`) check for null, if true, die with `mysql_error`. You are getting the error because your query is more than likely failing (ie. it is not returning a valid mysql resource for `mysql_fetch_array`. I would spend some time cleaning up your script as well... it is a mess! :)

Comment: I would really suggest using a framework like Cakephp or codeigniter  to create all this, debugging built in as well as security for forms etc

Comment: @Jakub : As it seems CherylAnnCe is still learning PHP. It's good to learn how to code the hard way before using any framework, that way you can understand the underlying logic.

Comment: Yes, @Jeff D, that is what I am working on doing. :-)

Comment: @JeffD, I disagree, CherylAnnCE will learn much more using a framework than piddling along with silly things like how do i connect to a db, or uploading a file, why re-write boiler plate code? Use a framework, and if you REALLY need to do the work, then do it.  Why make it harder on yourself? You still understand the code if you work with the framework, I think your argument is moot Jeff.

Comment: @Jakub, everything is in life is learn step by step, as a baby you crawled before you even walk or run, the same goes for programming. In the same lane, I wouldn't expect an OO beginner to use proper design patterns. Reinventing the wheel in a production context is bad, but in a learning context, it is the thing to do since you can compare what you have done with work made by others.

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql query is not going through, or it is retuning 0 rows.
Try to put this

```
if(!$resource){
echo mysql_error();   
echo ' <br>Query: .$sql;
}
```

statement directly after $resource = mysql_query($sql);

and see what it outputs. Also, make sure error reporting is turned on.

I edited my answer on your post yesterday, you might want to look at it; it may give you some ideas for a different approach.

The link is here:
[Fatal error: Call to undefined function getRecords() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Employees.php on line 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882852/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-getrecords-in-c-xampp-htdocs-employee/7882907#7882907)

Comment: Thank you, Ben, and for your detailed response to yesterday's question. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting any rows back.  Try changing this

```
function getRecords()
{
$sql = buildQuery();

$resource = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

to

```
function getRecords()
{
$sql = buildQuery();

echo $sql;
exit();

$resource = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

this will output the SQL you are querying against the database.  If it is not immediately apparent, copy and run this query against your database.  See if any rows come back.  If not then thats your problem!

---

Also you can use "echo mysql_error();" to get the text of the last error mysql threw.

EXAMPLE:

```
// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I added that and it still failed.

Comment: I added an edit about getting the latest error mysql threw. Might try that.

Answer (score 0):

Please never do such thing:

> > mysql_query("INSERT INTO employeeinfo (firstname, lastname, phone, email, department, position) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]', '$_POST[lastname]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[department]', '$_POST[position]')");

This will produce a HUGE hole in your site security called sql-injection.
You should always check any data gained from user.

The simple example of how it should be:

> > $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
> >     $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
> >     $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
> >     $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
> >     $department = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['department']);
> >     $position = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['position']);
> >
> > mysql_query("INSERT INTO employeeinfo (firstname, lastname, phone, email, department, position)
> >     VALUES ('{$firstname}', '{$lastname}', '{$phone}', '{$email}', '{$department}', '{$position}')");

For more info read: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

I think you should find a good book for novices in PHP and read at least from time to time it.
It will help you understand what you writing and how to make it better.

The first book that i googled for this purpose - [http://www.amazon.com/Learning-MySQL-JavaScript-Step-Step/dp/0596157134/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596157134)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.. just maybe there is some problem with your code..

```
function getRecords()
{
 $sql = buildQuery();

 $resource = mysql_query($sql);
}

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resource)) { // The error is for this row
$results[] = $row;
}
return $results;
```

my guess is that your above code should be something like this

```
function getRecords()
{
 $sql = buildQuery();

$resource = mysql_query($sql);
$results = array();
if($resource != null)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resource)) 
    {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
}

return $results;
}
```

Hope it helps :)